# Finding differences in .JSON files using Powershell Compare-Object, problems with square bracket values

Tags: json, powershell, variables, square-bracket, compareobject

I am trying to compare two .json files using

```
# Compare two files 
$BLF = (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\...\Documents\Android1.json)
$CLF =  (Get-Content -Path C:\Users\...\Documents\Android2.json)

$aUnsorted = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $BLF -DifferenceObject $CLF -IncludeEqual
```

I have written code to compare regular variables such as the below "passcodeBlockSimple", and register the value in one file vs the other. I would like to do the same with values that are defined inside brackets:

```
"variableName": [ 
                     "99"
                ]
```

I have a solution for when the two files have the same value, by adding onto the value until it finds the end-bracket ]. That gives "variableName": ["99"]. See the variable "roleScopeTagIds" below as an example of such a variable.

I would like to find the value when they are different, but the output from Compare-Object lists the difference line-by-line. Example below, where I loose the information about the variable "restrictedApps" when it is different in the two files (File1 has value "1" and File2 has Value "2").

```
InputObject                                               SideIndicator
-----------                                               -------------
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.iosCompliancePolicy",   ==           
    "roleScopeTagIds":  [                                 ==           
                            "0"                           ==           
                        ],                                ==           
    "version":  1,                                        ==           
    "passcodeMinutesOfInactivityBeforeScreenTimeout":  1, ==           
    "managedEmailProfileRequired":  false,                ==           
    "restrictedApps":  [                                  ==           
                       ],                                 ==           
        "passcodeBlockSimple":  false,                    =>           
                        "2"                               =>           
"passcodeBlockSimple":  true,                             <=           
                        "1"                               <=
```

The files are, File 1:

```
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.iosCompliancePolicy",
    "roleScopeTagIds":  [
                            "0"
                        ],
    "version":  1,
    "passcodeBlockSimple":  true,
    "passcodeMinutesOfInactivityBeforeScreenTimeout":  1,
    "managedEmailProfileRequired":  false,
    "restrictedApps":  [
                            "1"
                       ],
```

And File 2:

```
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.iosCompliancePolicy",
    "roleScopeTagIds":  [
                            "0"
                        ],
    "version":  1,
    "passcodeBlockSimple":  false,
    "passcodeMinutesOfInactivityBeforeScreenTimeout":  1,
    "managedEmailProfileRequired":  false,
    "restrictedApps":  [
                            "2"
                       ],
```

So my question is: How can i find the value of the variable when they are different, and the Compare-Object result is as above?

(I have to use the Compare-Object function)

Comment: Check out examples four and five of [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7) using the `-Property` parameter. You will want to convert your strings to a PSObject first with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7). Ensure that the strings are well formed for .NET.

Comment: Do I convert before or after the comparison? And also, there is no property that I know that separates the name and the value of the variable. They are all in the Value

Comment: Before the comparison. You should compare the converted objects. In your example above, I would set `roleScopeTagIds` and `restrictedApps` as the `-Property` value.

Answer (score 1):

I dont get it totally, becuase youre jsons are invalid, but this code should resolve your issue:

Json1:

```
{
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.iosCompliancePolicy",
    "roleScopeTagIds":  [
                            "0"
                        ],
    "version":  1,
    "passcodeBlockSimple":  true,
    "passcodeMinutesOfInactivityBeforeScreenTimeout":  1,
    "managedEmailProfileRequired":  false,
    "restrictedApps":  [
                            "1"
                       ]
}
```

Json2:

```
{
"@odata.type":  "#microsoft.graph.iosCompliancePolicy",
    "roleScopeTagIds":  [
                            "0"
                        ],
    "version":  1,
    "passcodeBlockSimple":  false,
    "passcodeMinutesOfInactivityBeforeScreenTimeout":  1,
    "managedEmailProfileRequired":  false,
    "restrictedApps":  [
                            "2"
                       ]
}
```

```
[Array]$FileSoll = Get-Content C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\1.json
[Array]$FileIst = Get-Content C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\2.json

    $FileSoll = $($FileSoll | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json) -split ([Environment]::NewLine)
    $FileIst = $($FileIst | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json) -split ([Environment]::NewLine)
    $diff = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FileSoll -DifferenceObject $FileIst
```

Returns the differences:

```
InputObject                        SideIndicator
-----------                        -------------
    "passcodeBlockSimple":  false, =>
                           "2"     =>
    "passcodeBlockSimple":  true,  <=
                           "1"     <=
```